# Bind controller scope to directive by bindToController as references not working

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular bindToController when i am trying to map controller scope as reference to a directive it doesn't works.

```
Example AS: 
app.controller('test',function($scope){
       $scope.reftodir = $scope;
       $scope.test = 'someconte';
    })

 in html referenced it as :

     <test-directive testscope = 'reftodir' iso-scope="test"/>


app.directive('testDirective',function(){

      return{
         scope:{
             isoScope: '='
         },
         bindToController: {
            testscope:'='
         },
      }
    })


  Suppose i have a function in controller as test_function, i need to call that function from directive with the help controller scope available from bindToController variable such as testscope.test_function().

but test_function is not available. Please provide any suggestions, Thanks in advance friends.
```

Comment: why would you do that, what is the use case?

Comment: I trying to build a table component for my application (as module which can be included in any applications), for dependency calculation it has hit a function to the respective controller.

Answer (score -1):

Your directive object should look like this:

```
return {

    controller: 'test',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
    scope: {
       testScope: '='
    }   

}
```

then in your controller you should be able to see your scopes like this:

```
app.controller('test',function(){

   this.testScope //scope is available here
})
```

note that we won't need $scope anymore if we bind to controller, and the `this` part is points to the controller it self

Comment: i have some isolated scoped variables in the directive, so that i need a reference of the controller scope to perform certain operations, while i am trying to set bindToController = true, isolated scoped variable get overriden.

Comment: can you provide an example, sorry I don't understand

Comment: this.testScope is undefined

Comment: @Richard have you passed any variables from the user code to the directive's attribute `test-scope`?